# Wordpress - check if current page has given tag ID

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using WordPress custom taxonomies.

How to check if the current page has `tag_ID = "XXX"` ?

If that is any help the URL on  the admin page looks like this:

```
http://localhost/website/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=company&ta‌g_ID=13&post_type=news
```

The code currently used, but not working:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

    the_post_thumbnail();

} else {


    if (is_object_in_term($post - > ID, 'post_tag', '13')) {
        // ID 13
    }
    if (is_object_in_term($post - > ID, 'post_tag', '12')) {
        // ID 12
    }
    if (is_object_in_term($post - > ID, 'post_tag', '14')) {
        // ID 14
    }

}
```

​

Comment: @Pekka - stackoverlow / wordpress anwser are seperate Q&A forum and majority of users use only one of them. So it does make sense to post it in two places.

Comment: @Pekka - this is what I have done. Both checked and research. Again, stackoverlow / wordpress anwser are seperate Q&A forum.

Comment: @NewUser, this is not fair, you should have tested those answers first and if those were failed then you could have do this.

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I have tested. Please see the comments below.

Comment: @Pekka - I have tested the solutions in the answers and added comments. They either do not work / solve the problem so I decide to re-post to bigger Q&A forum (stackoverflow).

Comment: Ah, okay, I overlooked that one comment. Fair enough, sorry. Still, the `is_object_in_term` approach sounds like the real deal. You could add a comment showing how *exactly* you used it, maybe it's just a small detail that's missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this could be useful (for given url in admin)

```
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow == 'edit-tags' && $_GET['ta‌g_ID'] == '123') // 123 is for example
{
    //
}
```

**Update:** for the front end

```
$tag_id=get_query_var('tag_id');
if($tag_id && $tag_id=='123') // 123 is for example
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: @SSheikh Heera - Thanks for the answer. The URL I have posted if for WordPress admin site - not the front end. So our front-page will not have `edit-tags` in the URL.

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood your question.

Comment: `if($tag_id && $tag_id=='123')` should be `if($tag_id = '123')`, should it not? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Actually, I tested first if `$tag_id` exists and then checked whether it's `123` or not but it's fine. You are welcome :-)

Comment: Sheikh Heera - checking if exist does make sens. What about double `==` ?

Comment: `=` will assign right side value to the left side variable and `==` will check the condition.

Comment: Even if inside the `if statement`?

Comment: The interesting thing is that the NOT operator does not work with this snippet.