# How to check that the a page uses a taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to edit a template's `header.php` file and I want to check if it has a taxonomy named "store". If so, then I need to extract it's `tag_ID`.

When I edit the page (it's not a WordPress Page type) I can see these values in the admin url:

```
taxonomy=store&tag_ID=720
```

So I know there is a way but I'm having trouble getting any good results. I tried the
method [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357556/wordpress-check-if-current-page-has-given-tag-id) to extract at least the `tag_ID` but I'm getting `NULL`:

```
$tag_id=get_query_var('tag_ID');
echo $tag_id; //NULL
```

**Edit:**

To be clear in regards to the `tag_ID` because it may be confusing, all I really want is to get the unique id of the requested page so I figure seeing first if it has a taxonomy named "store" and then getting the right one using the `tag_id`.

Comment: so in every page you want which page/post/taxonomy is calling.. right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS far as i understand your question, You should try this:-

```
$data = get_queried_object();
```

With this, you can get what page/post/taxonomy is being called.

Just print-out/var_dump this `$data` variable, you will get full object of page/post/taxonomy.

Hope this may help you.